# Java integer max test with clockwork modulus statement returning incorrect value

Tags: java, math, int, modulus

In class we're currently working with a "clockwise" modulus function - that is to say, a function which essentially works the same as Math.floorMod(int a, int b).

For class, I cannot use Math.floorMod(), and I have written this after researching the topic:

```
 /**
 * Computes {@code a} mod {@code b} as % should have been defined to work.
 *
 * @param a
 *            the number being reduced
 * @param b
 *            the modulus
 * @return the result of a mod b, which satisfies 0 <= {@code mod} < b
 * @requires b > 0
 * @ensures
 * 
 *          <pre>
 * 0 <= mod  and  mod < b  and
 * there exists k: integer (a = k * b + mod)
 *          </pre>
 */
public static int mod(int a, int b) {
    assert b > 0 : "Violation of: b > 0";
    return (((a % b) + b) % b);
}
```

Here's my issue. This function passes every case I throw at it, except one, where a = 2 and b = INTEGER.MAX_VALUE.

That should return 2, as floorMod does, however it returns 0. Is there anyway I can fix this without using floorMod?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at your return statement. What does `(a % b)` return in that case? What happens when you add `b` to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((a % b) + b)  // this does 2 + INTEGER.MAX and leads to an overflow
```

You can use the following to handle this and still keep the int values:

```
public static int mod(int a, int b) {
    assert b > 0 : "Violation of: b > 0";
    return (int) (( (long) (a % b) + b) % b );
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you. I don't think converting to a long will lose me any points, but we'll see. It's either that or an if statement, correct?

Comment: If there is another solution (without converting to long) feel free to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the definition of `Math.floorMod` as stated in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod-int-int-), you should return `a - (floorDiv(a, b) * b)`.

`floorDiv(a, b)` gives a different result than `a/b` only when the result of the division is negative and `a` is not divisible by `b`, in which case it returns `a/b - 1` (for example `floorDiv(-4, 3) == -2`, while`(-4 / 3) == -1`).

So if you implement according to this definition, you get :

```
public static int mod(int a, int b) {
    assert b > 0 : "Violation of: b > 0";
    int floorDiv = a/b;
    if ((a < 0) && (a % b != 0))
        floorDiv--;
    return a - (floorDiv * b);
}
```

BTW, this implementation is a subset of the implementation of the actual `Math.floorMod`, which allows both arguments to be negative.